# How to change default notebook background color?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, color, customization

How does one change the default notebook background color?

Comment: It should also be noted that for Wolfram Mathematica 11.0, if you go to Format, then StyleSheet, there is the option ReverseColor in case you want a "dark theme".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can `SetOptions` for the current notebook as:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> LightGreen]
```

to change the background to whatever colour you like. You can also supply an RGB colour as:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> RGBColor[0.9, 0.7, 0.7]]
```

---

Other possibilities for the first argument of `SetOptions` are

- `$FrontEnd` which will change the background for all notebooks and last across restarting Mathematica.
- `$FrontEndSession` which will change the background for all notebooks but won't be saved if you restart Mathematica.

Comment: @Brett Thanks for the edits. I've been trying to look at making changes to the stylesheet, but couldn't figure out which style to change. I thought `Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], Background -> LightBlue]` should work, but it doesn't. Any clue?

Comment: If you select the `All` item from the popup list of styles in the stylesheet editor, that should work.

Comment: @R.M you cannot use named colours in style sheets you have to use e.g. `Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], Background -> RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]]`

Comment: I like this answer because it will allow me to make changes programmatically, thanks

Comment: We could have some sort of FAQ item on changing notebook options globally, for the session or one notebook only, and the use of the option inspector.  We had several questions like this in the last couple of days.  What do you think about a [tag:faq] tag, similar to [c++-faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)?

Comment: @Szabolcs I think [tag:front-end-faq] and [tag:kernel-faq] might be worthy tags to have. Of course, we must regulate what gets tagged with these and what doesn't, but it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: YES! WHITE BACKGROUND WAS HURTING MY EYES!

Comment: There's something strange: My cursor gets invisible while it's over the notebook, hints?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Are you sure it's not just becoming horizontal? i.e., in between cells. I've been fooled by this a few times at the start

Comment: @rm-rf Oh, problem solved. Nevermind.

Comment: @rm-rf Oh, there's something that would be useful: How to change the default color of the text?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira If by "text", you mean input text (or code), then see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5932/5) of mine that describes the various tokens that control the different colours. If you mean normal text, then the idea is the same — you modify the stylesheet, except that now you choose `Text` from the dropdown menu instead of `StandardForm` or anything else.

Answer (score 18):

You could create a **custom stylesheet** that has a different background color and define it to be the default one. To do that, go to `Format | Edit Stylesheet`, select `All` in the "Choose a style" combo box. Select the appearing entry in the list below and set your appropriate style definitions for it, in your case that would be another background color using `Format | Background Color`. The new window should look somewhat like this:

[image]

You can now select `File | Save as`, and save the stylesheet window notebook somewhere. To make it available in the stylesheet choosing menu (`Format | Stylesheet`), save it in `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets`, where `$UserBaseDirectory` is your user directory. If you don't know where that is, simply execute `$UserBaseDirectory` in Mathematica and it will print its location. Once your newly created stylesheet is saved in that folder, you'll be able to select it over the menus; if it doesn't appear right away, restart the frontend.

If you want to use this as your default stylesheet, i.e. the one that is used when the program starts, go to the options inspector (`Format | Options Inspector`), select `Global preferences` at the top (see picture below), and change the value of `DefaultStyleDefinitions` to the path you put your stylesheet in.

[image]

Comment: The style sheet only changes the background color of all cells and not the notebook. How can I create a stylesheet where it changes only the the notebook background color?

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to pull up the **Format --> Option Inspector** selection in the menu system, select the notebook that you're using in the upper-left, and then navigate to **Notebook Options --> Display Options --> Background**. The palette would let you pick the exact shade that you wish to work with. You can also see a bunch of the great options that R.M. identified in the answer above through the Option Inspector.

It's a little clunky and the `SetOptions` command is quicker, but it is an alternative for tinkering and playing around with to get the Notebook set up to your satisfaction.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is just another way of getting at the notebook options, which I note as an alternative syntax to [R.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1390/8):

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Background] = Red;
```

The [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurrentValue.html) command can also be used to access a range of other (often system-specific) options like `"PanelFontSize"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to **Format->Edit stylesheet**, then you have to add the word "Notebook" where it says **"Enter a style name"**. The you can change its background color in **Format->background color** by selecting it.
Hope I could help!