# create subsubsubsection in Standard Report Style

Tags: stylesheet

I am working with Standard Report Style.
When I press for instance Alt+5 a Subsection is generated.
When I press Alt+6 Subsubsection is generated.
What I want is a creation of something like Alt+foo, which will create a Subsubsubsection.
Also, I want to know how exactly the Cell Subsubsubsection is generated.

Thanks

Comment: `FrontEndTokenExecute["Style", "Subsubsubsection"]` + [16165](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16165/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I failed to find a duplicate so here's the answer. The token you are looking for is `FrontEndTokenExecute["Style", "Subsubsubsection"]` or at least most probably but it seems to do what built in shortcuts do.

You can build it in as:

- `MenuCommand, KeyShortcut, NotebookEventActions`

  [16165](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16174/5478) by *Chris Degnen*
- `CellInsertionPointCell, AdditionalToolbar`

  [64218](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64218/5478)