# Hide the banner Mathematica 11.0.1 Student Edition

Tags: front-end, notebooks, docked-cell

I am trying to hide the "Student Edition" banner in Mathematica 11.0.1. I saw this close post: [Can the banner in the Home Edition be removed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11403/can-the-banner-in-the-home-edition-be-removed), which suggests to hide it via the Options Inspector under `WindowFrame -> "Generic"` instead of `"Normal"`.

However, when I try this, nothing happens. But when I select `"Frameless"` for example, the window's appearance effectively changes, but whatever style I choose, the banner is still there.

Would anyone know how to succesfully hide this banner? If it helps, I'm on OSX 10.11.6.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47468/5478 Notice that removing brading elements may be against the license.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks!

Comment: [Same question for the Home Edition Banner](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11403/5467). There are also interesting informations about legality.

Comment: @Kuba This also work for Linux(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @Kuba Where can I find `$UserBaseDirectory`. There is `$UserBaseDirectory.nb`

Comment: @L.K. SystemOpen @ $UserBaseDirectory you have to proceed analogously to: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80897/5478 so copy appropriate file from installation to userbasedirectory.