# How to remove a bar that blocks some upper space that says "WOLFRAM STUDENT EDITION" so forth?

Tags: interface, menu

[image: my Mathematica Screenshot]

There is a bar field on the upper screen of Mathematica that occupies some space, that says "Wolfram Mathematica : STUDENT EDITION" so forth.
I would like to utilize the field instead of letting it be used in a useless way.

How can I block the bar from apprearing?

Comment: possible duplicates: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11403/1364) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9471/1364)

Comment: @xslittlegrass Thank you for the informing!