# Looking for documentation on code editor's color/style highlighting

Tags: front-end, interface, syntax-highlighting

Where can I find reference documentation (as opposed to, e.g., tutorials, etc.) on the meanings of the various color/style highlightings that *Mathematica* automatically assigns to code as one types it?

I don't have any particular question; I just want to see what *all* these colors and styles mean.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5932/5), especially the second image...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know whether I interpret your question correctly but have you checked `Preferences`->`Appearance`?

There you see what the colors of the syntax highlighter mean:

[image]
[image]
[image]