# How to pick a color differing significantly from the colors already in a given color list?

Tags: color

Suppose that we want to color a number of objects. We start by selecting some color (randomly). Then we want the color of the next object to be significantly different from the colors already used (including the background color, say white). After a number of attempts I was unable to find any smart way to do this. Suppose that the `RGBColor` model is used. Then my best result was

```
cl = {RGBColor[1., 1., 1.]};

myFun1[colList_List, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}] := 
  Last[ColorDistance[colList, RGBColor[x, y, z], DistanceFunction->"CIE94"]]

oneStep1[cl_List] := 
  (Append[cl, RGBColor[x, y, z] /. 
     Last[NMaximize[
       {myFun1[cl, {x, y, z}], 1 >= x >= 0, 1 >= y >= 0, 1 >= z >= 0}, 
       {x, y, z}]]])

Nest[oneStep1, cl, 5]
```

Clearly, the result is not good enough (I need at leas 10 significantly different colors).

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't use a pre-defined color space? `Table[ColorData["BrightBands"][i], {i, 0, 1, .1}]` There are a number of both continuous and discrete sets.

Comment: @user18792 Isn't this the same question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38722/discrete-colordata-scheme-with-n-colors?

Comment: Or possibly this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/calculating-pleasant-colors-for-source-code-or-web-design/23649#23649?

Comment: Is it really necessary to search for suitable colors one after another? I think results should be more pleasant when they're optimized all together.

Comment: Predefined colors is not good for the following reasons:

Comment: 1) Objects are generated in the fly (i.e. I dont know in advance how many colors I will need) and  2) I want to give user a chance (an option) to select the color of  an object in time of generation. Under this circumstances it is clear that any predefined colors will interfere with user choice. @kirma solution gives good colors, however I would like a strategy, when number of colors is not known in advance.

Comment: @user18792 Personally, I would pre-generate large number of colors, and then find the "furthermost" color from all reference colors on this set and move this color as the next color to the reference color set, then repeat this process until color list to choose from is empty. This would allow some global planning, but also guarantee that colors being added start with clearly separate ones, and "fill the gaps" later on. Regarding a strategy - I suspect amount of properly distinct colors one can generate is relatively limited, and thus a pre-computed color list would be a good bet.

Comment: @kirma And then what to do with the user specified  colors? His/her choise is free (not limited to the pre-generated colors). Then I will still need procedure to find and remove pre-generated colors which are "closest" to the user's choice.

Comment: @user18792 Ah, yes, that considerably complicates the problem! In general, I'd want to replace Mma-supplied opaque `ColorDistance` function with a sufficiently good polynomial approximation, possibly optimized specifically for suprathreshold color difference measure (built-in color distance functions are really designed to measure perceptual "sameness" acceptability of colors, for instance for manufacturing and other reprocution purposes). I suspect this could drastically speed up computation of color groups.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one approach, attempting to find a sufficiently good local maximum for minimum color difference of ten colors differing from black and white, and each other:

```
Module[
 {sRGB, toLCH, oldcolors, ncolors, newcolorvars, newcolors, allcolors},
 sRGB = Import["sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc"];
 toLCH = ColorConvert[#, sRGB -> "LCH"] &;
 oldcolors = {Black, White};
 ncolors = 10;
 newcolorvars = Array[c, {ncolors, 3}];
 allcolors = Join[oldcolors, newcolorvars];
 newcolors = RGBColor @@@
   (newcolorvars /. Last@Quiet@NMaximize[
        Min[
         ColorDistance[toLCH@#1, toLCH@#2, 
            DistanceFunction -> "CIE2000"] & @@@ 
          Subsets[allcolors, {2}]],
        Flatten@newcolorvars \[Element] 
         Cuboid[Table[0, {3 ncolors}]],
        Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing", 
        MaxIterations -> 1000000000]);
 Join[oldcolors, newcolors]]
```

[image]

Pairwise comparison visualization of selected colors:

```
Table[Graphics@{Circle[], 
     Table[{#[[i]], 
         Disk[{0, 0}, 
          1, \[Pi]/2 - (2 \[Pi]/Length@#) {i - 1, i}]}, {i, 
         Length@#}] &@#, {i, Disk[{0, 0}, 2/3]}}, {i, #}] &@%
```

[image]

There are multiple problems in this implementation:

- `ColorDistance` seems to require unexplained pre-conversion to LCH colorspace to work acceptably. In general, there's something deeply disturbing in colorspace handling Mathematica does - or doesn't seem to do, sometimes. Linear and non-linear colorspaces are not intuitively separate, or compatible, for instance.
- `NMaximize` has trouble trying to find good maxima because `ColorDistance` is only numeric and the domain has lots of local maxima.
- `ColorDistance` functions in general are not even meant to perform large color separation measures, but rather ones very close to a reference color. (Related commentary: [Is ColorDistance symmetric?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86730/is-colordistance-symmetric))
- `Min` is not necessary a sensible aesthetic metric. Something like `Mean@# / Variance@# &` might make more sense, but is takes forever in practice.

Comment: _`ColorDistance` seems to require unexplained pre-conversion to LCH colorspace to work acceptably_ Could you make an example about this point? `ColorDistance` should work with any supported color directive.

_Linear and non-linear colorspaces are not intuitively separate, or compatible, for instance_ RGB-based spaces are non-linear, CIEXYZ is linear while LAB and LUV are not (L is a non-linear transformation of Y). Not sure about what you mean by _compatible_ here.

Comment: @Batracos This is really an unscientific hunch. I'm feeling that colors converted from "traditional" `RGBColor` to other spaces, or other spaces to `RGBColor` getting displayed on the notebook sometimes fail to observe linearity (or non-linearity) correctly. I haven't really pinpointed an exact way to demonstrate this, though.