# How to put Black as the background colour, and text as white in Mathematica?

Tags: functions

My question is equal to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34237/invert-colors-stylesheet-white-on-black),even though by different reasons.
I would like to know how can I change the white background to black, and the black text to white.

I'm asking again, since a year has passed and no answers were given to the question in the link.
Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: Not sure which tag to use.