# How to change the default Notebook stylesheet

Tags: front-end, notebooks, stylesheet, customization, default

For everyday work I use a custom notebook template. Its name DefaultModified.nb However, in order to open it I need to first open a built-in default notebook, go to the Menu/Format/StyleSheet and define the style that I need.

**My question**: Is it possible to fix in Mma a style of the notebook that will open by default? In my case the DefaultModified.nb.

Note that I do not want to kill or change the Default.nb style. Let it be in case that something goes wrong. I only want to ask Mma to open another template by default.

Comment: You can use `DefaultStyleDefinitions` but I'd rename yours to `Default.nb` and put it in `$UserBaseDirectory/...` so that notebooks have a valid `StyleDefinitions` when sent to others.

Comment: @Kuba How to use the DefaultStyleDefinitions?  Yes, I understan that I could simply rename DefaultModified.nb into Defalt.nb. My point is, however, that I do not want to destroy the Default.nb

Comment: You don't have to destroy it, it is in `$InstallationDirectory` while yours would be in `$UserBaseDirectory`. I haven't tried `DefaultStyleDefinitions` but I suppose `SetOptions[$FrontEnd...` should work.

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1391/44141)

Comment: You begin the question by referring to a template. Later it appears that you want to set a default stylesheet? If you want to globally set the default stylesheet that opens with each new notebook then doing that in the options inspector is probably easiest

Comment: @ Mike Honeychurch Yes, that' s what I also expected. However, when I go to OptionInspector/GlobalOptions/FileLocations/DefaultNotebook, or DefaultStyleDefinitions the corresponding items are not accessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultStyleDefinitions.html),

> `DefaultStyleDefinitions` is a global option that specifies the default stylesheet for all new notebooks.
>
> The stylesheet must be located in a directory that is listed in `StyleSheetPath`.

Note that this option affects not only on-screen display, but also [determines the default styles used by `Export`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139948/280).

By convention the custom user stylesheets should be located in the user profile
directory:

```
dir = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}];
```

If the directory doesn't exists one should create it:

```
If[! DirectoryQ[dir], CreateDirectory[dir]];
```

You should put your custom stylesheet "DefaultModified.nb" in this directory and then set it as the default via

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, DefaultStyleDefinitions] = "DefaultModified.nb";
```

After restarting the FrontEnd all the new Notebooks will have this stylesheet by default.

---

It is worth to mention that according to [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139999/automatic-recognition-of-a-custom-stylesheet#comment378897_140280), `StyleDefinitions` are always set as a path relative to directories on `StyleSheetPath`, for example one can specify `` StyleDefinitions -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Lectures"}, "styles.nb"] `` for a stylesheet `"styles.nb"` in a directory `"Lectures"` located wherever on `StyleSheetPath`. The same should be true for `DefaultStyleDefinitions`.

Comment: Do not use this method with 12.1, it produces curious results (in my case, unevaluatable cells). Use the method described in the article in Wolfram Support linked by ktm.

Answer (score 10):

Wolfram has an article discussing precisely this:

http://support.wolfram.com/kb/29974