Trying to get rid of cell and notebook (?) dingbats from ages ago
Years ago, I must have changed my stylesheet or something and put in clubs (the card suit) as cell dingbats. I'd like to get rid of them. I can turn them off manually, but the change does stick, and I still have this annoying dingbat to the left of the notebook WOLFRAM MATHEMATICA | HOME EDITION "letterhead". Can anyone help me out? I haven't touched stylesheets or Option Inspector in ages. Thank you! 

Examine Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]. If it's not too long, you might post it. In any case. I'd probably suggest trying SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]. But I'd want to keep the output of Options[EvaluationNotebook[]] around, in case I accidentally messed something up.

Also check out DefaultStyleDefinitions, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultStyleDefinitions.html . See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132349/how-to-change-the-default-notebook-stylesheet

Look for the options of NotebookImport[] in the documentation.
