# Is there a way to make the whole document black in Default stylesheet?

Tags: color, fonts, style

I want to change the text color of the whole document to black, because it makes it more readable after printing with a black and white printer. Is there a way to make all document black **with one command**?

I can change the text color for individual cells with Format > Text Color menu. If I select the outer cell and change it to black the Section and Subsection titles still remain brown.

I am using default stylesheet and Mathematica 11.0.1.0.

Comment: May be like this: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor -> Black]`. Check http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1390/19742

Comment: Thanks @AnjanKumar, I have added this column in a new cell and selected Evaluate > Evaluate Notebook. It did not change the colors.

Comment: You don't have to evaluate the whole notebook. Just evaluate the above command.

Comment: I tied evaluating one command, same result, it did not change the colors in the document.

Comment: What you see is not what you get after printing. First switch Format / Switch Envioronment to printout and compare that.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the tip. Unfortunately does not turn to black in after I switch to Printout environment after evaluating this command.