# How can i change IDE color theme of Mathematica Wolfram?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, color, stylesheet

I'm a new in mathematica wolfram, please help how can i change  IDE colors theme's, text and background? I can't work with bright white screen?
I use Mathematica 12.1. and want color theme like a matrix-color(black-green).
I can't add tag #background in this site.

Comment: Do you mean https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/where-can-i-find-a-dark-stylesheet-for-mathematica or  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/how-to-change-default-notebook-background-color or https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-Black-or-Dark-theme-for-Mathematica?

Comment: Yes, i think invert color it is answer! I think, you can add tag like #IDE-color-theme or #backgroung, it  be useful.

Comment: We do already have the stylesheet tag which I think captures most of the questions on how to style the notebooks, their backgrounds, and even syntax highlighting.

Comment: May be #IDE-color-theme or something clouse to #IDE-stylesheet (indeed about IDE) this can be different from stylesheets of diagramm or presentation? There are many answers about diagram's styles, but IDE-stylesheets topic very deep under it.

Comment: Take a look at the [Dracula Theme](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DraculaTheme)